# Count similar events in the previous 7 days

Tags: pandas, group-by, time-series, rolling-computation, windowing

I'm trying to calculate event recurrence over the last 7 days. An event is defined by a specific amount deducted from my bank account (see dataframe example below). I tried using various tools such as rolling, groupby, resample, etc. but couldn't integrate them into a working solution. 2 main problems I encountered:

1. I need to perform rolling.count() only if the amount is equal
2. I need a full 7 day window and NOT 7 row window (some days there are no transactions)

Any ideas? I would really appreciate an explanation as well.  Thank you!!

```
date        description     amount       desired column (amount count in the last 7 days)
9/5/2019    asdkfjlskd      500          1
9/6/2019    dfoais          1200         1
9/7/2019    sadlfuhasd\     -12.99       1
9/8/2019    sdaf            500          2
9/9/2019    sdaf            -267.01      1
9/10/2019   sdaf            -39.11       1 
9/11/2019   sdaf            -18          1
9/11/2019   sdaf            500          3
9/13/2019   sdaf            500          1
9/14/2019   sdaf            -450         1
9/15/2019   sdaf            -140         1 
9/16/2019   sdaf            -6.8         1
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this in pandas is to use groupby-rolling, with the rolling window equal to seven days ('7D'), like that:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index("date").groupby("amount").rolling("7D").count()
```

This results in:

```
amount  date    
-450.00 2019-09-14  1.0
-267.01 2019-09-09  1.0
-140.00 2019-09-15  1.0
-39.11  2019-09-10  1.0
-18.00  2019-09-11  1.0
-12.99  2019-09-07  1.0
-6.80   2019-09-16  1.0
500.00  2019-09-05  1.0
        2019-09-08  2.0
        2019-09-11  3.0
        2019-09-13  3.0
1200.00 2019-09-06  1.0
```

Note that the date in this time frame relates to the end of the 7-day period. That is, in the 7 days ending on 2019-09-13, you had 3 transactions of 500.

and if you want to 'flatten' it back to a row per transaction:

```
tx_count = df.set_index("date").groupby("amount").rolling("7D").count()
tx_count.columns=["similar_tx_count_prev_7_days"]
tx_count = tx_count.reset_index()
tx_count
```

results in:

```
         amount date        similar_tx_count_prev_7_days
0       -450.00 2019-09-14  1.0
1       -267.01 2019-09-09  1.0
2       -140.00 2019-09-15  1.0
3       -39.11  2019-09-10  1.0
4       -18.00  2019-09-11  1.0
```

Comment: this is great! Thanks for the explanation. now how do I merge this to the original data frame?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used the following method. Is it less efficient?

```
df3['test']=df3.apply(lambda x : df3[(df3['amount']== x.amount) & (df3['date'] < x.date ) & (df3['date'] >= (x.date-pd.DateOffset(days=7)))]['date'].count(), axis=1)
```

Comment: I think it’s less efficient, as ‘apply’ of your lambda function doesn’t use the vector computation capabilities of pandas.